# Specification pattern using Entity Framework (order by property)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting, linq-to-entities, specification-pattern

I want to write some API to sort entities on server side (SQLServer) using LINQ2Entities.

I have class which contains expression represents sorting field of entity and sorting direction :

```
    public class SortOption<TEntity>
    {
       public SortOption(Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> keySelector, 
            bool ascending = true)
        {
            KeySelector = keySelector;
            Ascending = ascending;
        }

       public Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> KeySelector { get; private set; }
       public bool Ascending { get; private set; }
    }
```

For each of my entities I have class which inherits from above. For example:

```
    public class PostSorting: SortOption<PostEntity>
    {
        public PostSorting(): base(p => p.Published)
        {
        }
    }

    public class PostEntity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Published { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

The main goal is to use properties of the SortOption class in my repository's method, which returns entities:

```
  public class Repository<TEntity>
     {
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> List(SortOption<TEntity> sortOptions)
         {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query;

            if (sortOptions.Ascending)
              query = dbSet.OrderBy(sortOptions.KeySelector);
            else
              query = dbSet.OrderByDescending(sortOptions.KeySelector);

            return query;
         }
     }
```

*"dbSet" field is `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>`

If I try to sort entities by any property which have type that differs from string type using PostSorting class I get an error like this:

```
"LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.".
```

For example(sorting by Published field):

```
 "Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, 
    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type
     'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."
```

or (if I want to order by Modified field)

```
 "Unable to cast the type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.Object'.
 LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."
```

of (if I want to order by Id field)

```
 "Unable to cast the type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Object'. 
 LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."
```

I worked on this task for several days but I can not find the answer to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this:

```
public static class QueryableEx
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> OrderByEx<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, object>> keySelector)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }
        if (keySelector == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
        }

        // While the return type of keySelector is object, the "type" of 
        // keySelector.Body is the "real" type *or* it is a
        // Convert(body). We rebuild a new Expression with this "correct" 
        // Body (removing the Convert if present). The return type is
        // automatically chosen from the type of the keySelector.Body .
        Expression body = keySelector.Body;

        if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            body = ((UnaryExpression)body).Operand;
        }

        LambdaExpression keySelector2 = Expression.Lambda(body, keySelector.Parameters);
        Type tkey = keySelector2.ReturnType;

        MethodInfo orderbyMethod = (from x in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                                    where x.Name == "OrderBy"
                                    let parameters = x.GetParameters()
                                    where parameters.Length == 2
                                    let generics = x.GetGenericArguments()
                                    where generics.Length == 2
                                    where parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(generics[0]) && 
                                        parameters[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(generics[0], generics[1]))
                                    select x).Single();

        return (IOrderedQueryable<TSource>)source.Provider.CreateQuery<TSource>(Expression.Call(null, orderbyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[]
        {
            typeof(TSource),
            tkey
        }), new Expression[]
        {
            source.Expression,
            Expression.Quote(keySelector2)
        }));
    }
}
```

You'll have to write a `OrderByAscending`, but it is the same just with replacing of `OrderBy` with `OrderByAscending`. The method rewrites the `Expression` to use the "right" type.

The code is heavily inspired from the [Queryable.OrderBy](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,7a2005ae434e9d9d).

Comment: @malonowa Are you using the `OrderByEx` method?

Comment: Yes, I have changed query like this query = _dbSet.                 OrderByEx(sortOptions.KeySelector) and made changes in ctor and property "KeySelector" in SortOption class: keySelector is type of Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>

Comment: @malonowa Fixed. Modified code around big comment. From the big comment  to the LambdaExpression keySelector2 (included)

Comment: Xanatos, I don't understand how, but it works! Thank you a lot!

Comment: This worked great for OrderBy and OrderByDescending, but I tried to reuse for ThenBy and ThenByDescending and get "Sequence contains no elements." on the line where `MethodInfor orderbyMethod` is assigned. Any help would be appreciated. I've duplicated the code as a ThenByHelper so I could play with it a bit.

Comment: @xanatos. To get this working for ThenBy, I commented out the following lines: `where parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(generics[0]) && parameters[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(generics[0], generics[1]))`. I tested for both OrderBy methods and ThenBy methods and only 1 was returned. It worked well. Any side effect from this that you see?

Comment: @LúfarSolutions You should look at the signature of `ThenBy` more carefully. Replace the `parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(generics[0]) && ` with `parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(generics[0]) && `

Comment: @LúfarSolutions The complex query is for future-proofing: you don't have any guarantee that in one of the next versions of .NET Microsoft won't add a second `ThenBy` overload with slightly different parameters. By looking for the exact signature you want, you protect yourself from this.

Comment: @xanatos I tried altering the query as you suggested prior to my comment as I did notice the signature difference but it didn't get it to work. I'll give it another look though. Thanks!